# Table already utf8 charset, still getting question marks in some characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mbstring

I'm trying to change my encoding to utf-8, below is what I have so far.

Table Charset

[image: my table]

mbstring installed

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

mbstring configured in `php.ini`

```
mbstring.language = Neutral
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation = On /*updated it to mbstring.encoding_translation = 0*/
mbstring.http_input = auto         /*updated it to mbstring.http_input = pass*/
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8       /*updated it to mbstring.http_output = pass*/
mbstring.detect_order = auto  
mbstring.substitute_character
default_charset = UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload = 7
```

Header

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

HTML meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

HTML CODE

```
<label for="article_body_pun">Article (Foreign): </label>
<textarea cols="100" rows="10" name="article_body_pun"></textarea><br />
```

PHP

```
$article_body_pun   = $_REQUEST['article_body_pun'];
```

SQL

```
$insert_article = "INSERT INTO articles(article_body_pun) 
                      VALUES ('{$article_body_pun}'')";
```

PHP to insert

```
$article_query = mysqli_query($connectDB, $insert_article);
```

Data that should be stored -> `汉语`

Original Data stored

```
Ã¦Â±Â‰Ã¨Â¯Â
```

Upon adding `mysqli_set_charset($connectDB, "utf8");` as suggested by @Pekka 웃, output became (*commented below as well*)

```
æ±è¯
```

after some troubleshooting, data partially stored correctly.

```
�?语
```

tried checking the charset by `mb_detect_encoding`, and getting `UTF-8` on the results pulled.

and upon checking the charset in firefox.

[image]

That seems to be correct, but still getting question marks on some characters. Any further suggestions to make this work?

Comment: +1 for a complete, well-structured question! You are missing some things though, namely setting the connection encoding to UTF-8. Check out [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: @Pekka웃, any suggestion with the changes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with help of a friend, the data was not inserted correctly from my HTML form to Database. Seems like my mbstring configurations were causing the problem, had to update the following:

```
mbstring.http_input = pass
mbstring.http_output = pass
mbstring.encoding_translation = 0
```

so the values are just reverted back to default and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to @Pekka 웃 and @Willem for their help.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there: make sure the mySQL connection is also encoded UTF-8.

Check out [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for details.

Comment: before the text stored was like `Ã¦Â±Â‰Ã¨Â¯Â­`. After inserting the following code `mysqli_set_charset($connectDB, "utf8");` I'm getting this `æ±è¯`­, instead it should look like this `汉语`.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. The page that contains the form is UTF-8 encoded and it shows so in the browser, correct?

Comment: in my database actually, using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @vephelp Is it possible that your phpmyadmin webpage simply doesn't render the database content correctly, can you try checking the database content outside of the phpmyadmin environment?

Comment: @Willem yes, currently I'm retrieving the data into the browser itself, and getting the output included in my recent edit above.

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through#comment-22638702 ? It may account for your, as you stated, partially correct results

Comment: @Pekka웃, have added `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in header of the output page. So I guess that is UTF-8 now. Not sure though.

Comment: @vephelp Do you have a live link?

Comment: 汉 in unicode is 6C49, 4 bytes, according to the comment located in my earlier link, the 'normal' utf-8 encoding used in MySQL stores unicode characters up to 3 bytes, consider trying the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html mysql character encoding.

Comment: @Willem Just to confirm, isn't 语 4 bytes as well? unicode value is 8BED. If yes, then why is that getting stored properly?

Comment: @Willem, I'm quiet new at this but just read that utf8 is acutally 8 bytes. So I guess that shouldn't be an issue. I guess, haha!

Comment: and that I guess is for the PHP part, but mysql is 3bytes haha! nice info!

Comment: @vephelp nope, UTF-8 is 1 to 4 bytes per character. MySQL draws the line at 3 bytes though

Comment: ow ok, @Pekka웃 so I will have to use utf8mb4 charset for my database? But what I've read around is all about utf8, they say it works fine.

Comment: @vephelp yeah, in theory mySQL's UTF-8 supports all characters in the so-called "basic multilingual plane" which `汉` should be in. Not sure what is going on here

Comment: @vephelp your character is 3 bytes and should be ok: `E6 B1 89`  http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E6%B1%89

Comment: mhhm. I'm sort of unsure now on what else to do.